# OpenLayers Filters for GeoJSON Source

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, openlayers-6

I'm using OpenLayers (v6.3.1) with [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) extensions (to handle animated clustering) on a simple html/javascript/jquery project.

I succeeded displaying data from a geojson with a vector source passed to cluster source then added to a layer.
My goal is now to add/remove filters (by user interaction) to the geojson fields displayed on the map.

The code of vector/cluster sources and the cluster layer :

```
const clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: `${URL_PATH}`,
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    })
});

const clusterLayer = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
    name: 'Cluster',
    source: clusterSource,
    animationDuration: $("#animatecluster").prop('checked') ? 700 : 0,
    // Cluster style
    style: getStyle
});
```

I'm stuck on the filtering part : should I filter the features array and replace the source of my layer? Or is there a easier way to do it with Openlayers?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can filter using the `geometryFunction` option in `ol.source.Cluster`

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your quick answer ! I understand the `geometryFunction` as an option which calculates if a feature should join a cluster. However, my goal is to implement a filter applying not only on clusters (or during clustering) but to all features even single ones

Comment: For other vector layers you can control what is displayed using a style function by returning a style only if the feature satisfies the filter